# Div around two-columns div should dynamicaly change it's height when opening the inner divs (jQuery-ui portlets)

Tags: css, jquery-ui, html, portlet

How can i make the div around a two column division(jQuery-ui portlets) arrangement dynamically change it's height, when I open the divs in the left column?
When I open the divs (portlets) on the right columns the text and the div below and the text glides down whereas when i open divs in the left column they just appear above the rest of the page.

I've created a fiddle to show my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/EVq5T/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear the floats....

```
.example{
background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-600-20-1.jpg');
height: 20px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
clear: both;    /* <----- added this line */
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVq5T/6/)

Comment: Ok, then the green div does what I want, but when I open both portlets on the left side they're still bigger than the parent div with the grey background.

Comment: The tip was good. I had to add the clear on another spot, too. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EVq5T/7/